# Why isn't the templated function type being deduced?

Tags: c++, templates

Why do I have to provide the third argument if it's defaulted?

```
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
void createLabelValuePair(const std::string& label, getter_t&& getter, setter_t&& setter = char())
{


}

int main()
{
    createLabelValuePair("t", []() { return 0; });
}
```

Doesn't work, gives error:

> no instance of function template "createLabelValuePair" matches the
> argument list

but:

```
int main()
{
    createLabelValuePair("t", []() { return 0; }, char());

}
```

Works

Comment: Because a template parameter, and a function parameter, are two different things. Before instantiating a template function, at which point any default parameters get worked out, the template parameters must be specified. Simply specify a default value for the template parameter, too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The template parameter type should be deduced from the argument parameters passed, as shown by when specifically passing it. It's just that it's a default argument.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction "_Type template parameter cannot be deduced from the type of a function default argument_"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, template argument deduction does not consider function default arguments. Its a non-deduced context as listed here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

> In the following cases, the types, templates, and non-type values that are used to compose P do not participate in template argument deduction, but instead use the template arguments that were either deduced elsewhere or explicitly specified. If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.

> 4. A template parameter used in the parameter type of a function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in the call for which argument deduction is being done:

You can use two seperate overloads:

```
#include <string>

template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t>
void createLabelValuePair(const std::string& label, getter_t&& getter, setter_t&& setter) {}

template <typename getter_t>
void createLabelValuePair(const std::string& label, getter_t&& getter) {
    createLabelValuePair(label,getter,char());
}

int main() {
    createLabelValuePair("t", []() { return 0; });
}
```

Alternatively provide a default for the template argument:

```
template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t = char>
void createLabelValuePair(const std::string& label, getter_t&& getter, setter_t&& setter = setter_t()) {}
```

Comment: Or, default the template instead, and use the template to default the parameter: `template <typename getter_t, typename setter_t = char>
void createLabelValuePair(const std::string& label, getter_t&& getter, setter_t&& setter = setter_t())`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, added. There was a reason I considered it as not nice, but now I dont remember anymore, perhaps it was just my confusion ;)

Comment: I would use `setter_t()` or `setter_t{}` instead of `char()` for the default parameter value. It will still default to `char()` when `setter_t` is `char`, but other types can be used or `setter_t` that may not be compatible with `char`